# Extjs4 and TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, extjs, tinymce

I found menual for **ExtJS3**, and there was ux component of **TinyMCE**. I want to use it in **ExtJS4**. How can I do it and where to find manuals about using TinyMCE in ExtJS4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they included anything for TinyMCE in ExtJs4. They do have standard HTML editor component though.

Comment: But there need to be some way to integrate Tiny in the ExtJS. I want to do that, but don't know how..

Comment: It's very possible there will not be an easy way to integrate them, since Tiny was designed for ExtJs3 and you're trying to use 4.

Comment: I found very easy way http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149284-TinyMCE-width-ExtJS&highlight=tinymce

Answer (score 2):

The following solution covers many issues of the integration:

- Initialization in an initially visible and in an initially invisible tab.
- Correct place occupation by the initialization in any ExtJS layout.
- Correct resizing by the resizing of the underlying text area.
- Activation and deactivation of the WYSIWYG editor. Keeping of the cursor position by switching to the HTML text modus.
- Enabling and disabling of the WYSIWYG editor control.
- Changing of WYSIWYG settings and CSS file for the editable contents on the fly.
- Pre-formatting of the HTML text in visible and invisible modus.
- Focusing of the WYSIWYG editor control.
- Marking invalid.
- Tracking dirty state.
- Skin "extjs" and the native ExtJS windows for the editor inline popups.
- Storing and restoring cursor position by inserting of a place holder over a popup window.

http://www.point-constructor.com/en/tinyta/

Answer (score 1):

Harald Hannek has been doing a very nice work integrating TinyMCE and Extjs4, also he has really cool ux plugins that might be of the interest of anyone, so I think it's never too late to reply :)
Check it in github https://github.com/harrydeluxe/extjs-ux

Answer (score 0):

The docs for ExtJS 4 are linked from the top right of their website under the navigation option 'documentation',

here's a direct link too: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

Comment: I mean, that I need manual about using ExtJS4 and TinyMCE, not just ExtJS4 docs. I know, where are Ext4 docs.